# How to execute the same JQuery code for different html elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good evening and good night where ever you are,
I am just a beginner at web developing and working on a little project for learning.

i have a problem (which I am sure it's very simple but i have no idea what should i do)

i have this code where i was trying to fill rate-stars depending on a value for each one:

```js
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
    });
}

for (i = 1; i< 3 ; i++) {
    var val = 'input[name=amount'+i+']';
    var id = 'saj' + i;
    var submit = '#sa' + i;
    var extendedId = '#so' + i;

    $(function() {          
        $(submit).click(function() {
            $(extendedId).html('<span id = "'+id+'" class="stars">'+parseFloat($(val).val())+'</span>');
            $('#'+id).stars();
        });         
        $(submit).click();
    });
}
```

```css
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
}

span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.sajed {
    display :none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class = "sajed" type="text" name="amount1" value="2.5" />
<input id = "sa1" class = "sajed" type="submit" value="update"/>
<p id = "so1" ><span >2.4618164</span></p>

<input class = "sajed" type="text" name="amount2" value="4" />
<input id = "sa2" class = "sajed" type="submit" value="update"/>
<p id = "so2"><span >2.4618164</span></p>
```

I got this code from internet, I needed to add it several times, it's working if I repeat html,css(with different class name), and jquery's functions.

what i wanted to do is to add the html code several times and use the same css and JQuery on it

I have to stars element, I am calling the above function inside a for loop but only the LAST element in the loop has the effect.

when i start the for loop from 0 to 1 just the FIRST stars got the shape
when i start the for loop from 0 to 2 just the SECOND stars got the shape
when i start the for loop from 0 to 3 NOTHING HAPPENS.

I am sorry for that bad illustration but i hope you got what i mean from the code and the next picture which has the result i got

the first one happens when the loop ends at index 1 and the second when it ends at 2 and the third when it ends at indexes bigger than 2

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XPrm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop finishes before any of the click handlers execute, therefore your variables will be set to their final value, giving you the effect that you see.

You can solve this by using `let` instead of `var`: that way the variables (like `id`) become local to the `for` loop block, and the event handler function will reference the right one.

Another thing which you should correct in `$.fn.star`: a jQuery plug-in function will have `this` set to the jQuery collection to which the method is applied. That means it already is jQuery, and you should not wrap `this` in `$(this)`. Just do `this.each(...)`.

Comment: I started to love this website..
as you were waiting for me to post XD
that definitely worked
thanks for helping, i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think there is no need for `.each()` loop in your plugin and the `for loop` as well .. you can make your code like this

```js
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return //$(this).each(function() {
        $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
    //});
}
$(function() {          
    $('input[id^="sa"]').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ThisIt = $(this);
        ThisIt.next('[id^="so"]').html('<span class="stars">'+parseFloat(ThisIt.prev('input[name^="amount"]').val())+'</span>');
        ThisIt.next('[id^="so"]').find(' > span').stars();
    }).click();
});
```

```css
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
}

span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.sajed {
    /*display :none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class = "sajed" type="text" name="amount1" value="2.5" />
<input id = "sa1" class = "sajed" type="submit" value="update"/>
<p id = "so1" ><span >2.4618164</span></p>

<input class = "sajed" type="text" name="amount2" value="4" />
<input id = "sa2" class = "sajed" type="submit" value="update"/>
<p id = "so2"><span >2.4618164</span></p>
```

Comment: thanks for concerning .. that was a nice one :)))) thanks.